# Encrypt an sql script to be run on a server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Our company has a proprietary t-sql script that we need to run on several SQL servers that are not owned by us. We would like a way to run this script so that it couldn't be copied via the file system or the clipboard. We usually login via a remote session (logmein or similar) so we are concerned a tech who has seen us run one script could prepare the next server to copy the script, by knowing how we would run it.

All the records the script creates will be in the db for them to view, we just wish to protect the script itself.

Is there any method that would not require significant development?

Comment: I'm not aware that it's possible to make the execution of SQL scripts non-supervisable. I don't think it can be done. (And an off-topic side note: Why should the owners of the target SQL Servers not be allowed to know just what you're doing to their servers? Strikes me as odd. At least from a security point-of-view.)

Comment: No there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to fully protect your script (it can always be captured) but if you don't want to distribute it as is for easy copy/paste you could make an application that does nothing more than connect to the database and run the script, and embed the script as an encrypted ressource in your application.

However i would simply suggest you don't do any of that and just trust your Customer, a situation where you don't trust your direct custom, with whom you're in direct contact, strikes me as very bad. It's also often very poorly thought out, you're imagining it as having more value than it has most likely.

Comment: Running the script from an application won't help. AFAIK, the server owners can have all the incoming SQL commands logged (i.e. record the incoming Tabular Data Stream), and then "reverse engineer" the script from that log.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i said, it only prevents the simple copy/paste but it can still be captured

Comment: Ah, sure. I read that second part of your first paragraph too fast and missed its point. Sorry for that. +1 to your answer, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you can use WITH ENCRYPTION option while creating the stored procedure or function
so that underlying SQL can't be viewed but it can still be executed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

Comment: I'm pretty sure it only obfuscate the procedure after entering it (so if they log the create procedure command, they'd get the procedure text unencrypted). Also the doc indicates it doesn't protect against administrators who can still read it in the system tables.

Comment: WITH ENCRYPTION is trivial to break. This will keep any nontechnical people from viewing your code but it really doesn't do much.